# How does de-myelination occur in multiple sclerosis?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy, genetics

From what I understand, only the oligodendrocytes are affected in multiple sclerosis, and they are attacked by T cells which cross the blood-brain barrier. This leads me to two questions:

1. How is the blood-brain barrier affected in MS that allows T lymphocytes to cross the barrier?
2. Why do the T lymphocytes attack the oligodendrocytes? And when they do, what is the mechanism for de-myelination?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for Biology.SE

Comment: Voted for deletion as it is answered on Bio: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30242/how-does-de-myelination-occur-in-multiple-sclerosis